# How to configure "number" of hit-highlights returned by Sharepoint Search Server?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

We have a sharepoint server 2016 on premise and I would like to configure the number of hit highlights that are returned.

For e.g., if my query is "all hands landscape", I get a search result that highlights the words "all" and "hands". That is,

```
"hitHighlightSummary": "Calendar Invitation DL: Engineering <c0>All</c0> <c0>Hands</c0> ; Future Schedule: Date <ddd/> ",
```

However, the same page also contains the word "landscape" somewhere in it.

Is it possible to configure sharepoint to highlight "landscape" as well?

Perhaps some configuration property to set max hit highlights to 4 instead of the apparent 2.